# How to get data grouped by hour in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to build a query to get data count per hour for a particular day(or today). Main issue I am getting is I have to show count for all 24 hours in a day even if data does not exist for that particular hour. At that time it has to show count as zero. As of now I have come up with following query.

```
SELECT   Hour
  ,      COUNT(created_on) AS `user_count`
FROM     users
  RIGHT JOIN (
                   SELECT  0 AS Hour
         UNION ALL SELECT  1 UNION ALL SELECT  2 UNION ALL SELECT  3
         UNION ALL SELECT  4 UNION ALL SELECT  5 UNION ALL SELECT  6
         UNION ALL SELECT  7 UNION ALL SELECT  8 UNION ALL SELECT  9
         UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12
         UNION ALL SELECT 13 UNION ALL SELECT 14 UNION ALL SELECT 15
         UNION ALL SELECT 16 UNION ALL SELECT 17 UNION ALL SELECT 18
         UNION ALL SELECT 19 UNION ALL SELECT 20 UNION ALL SELECT 21
         UNION ALL SELECT 22 UNION ALL SELECT 23
  )      AS AllHours ON HOUR(created_on) = Hour
WHERE    created_on BETWEEN '2013-04-26' AND NOW() OR created_on IS NULL
GROUP BY Hour
ORDER BY Hour
```

Comment: Does this work? Seems like it could work... so your issue is your looking for something better than this?

Comment: This is not showing all 24 hours. It is skipping few hours.

Answer (score 2):

Just change the `GROUP BY` to:

```
GROUP BY HOUR(created_on)
```

And your query shall be:

```
SELECT   HOUR(created_on) AS Hour,
         COUNT(created_on) AS `user_count`
FROM     users
WHERE    created_on BETWEEN '2013-04-26' AND NOW() OR created_on IS NULL
GROUP BY HOUR(created_on)
ORDER BY Hour
```